# How to bind an array or an object from a shared factory?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an Angular factory called `Model` which is shared across multiple controllers.
Basically this `Model` encapsulate properties and helpers methods.

I'm trying now to bind this model with my view and I have a strange behaviour, The nested objects of `Model` and the array of objects are not bind properly.

I think this issue is caused by the fact that i'm trying to modify an object inside an other object by reference. Maybe i have lost the context for the nested elements ?

How can i solve this problem ?

Here is my app :

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('Blog', function() {
  function Blog(id) {
    this.load(id);
  }

  Blog.prototype = {
    name: "",
    description: [{
      value: ""
    }, {
      value: ""
    }, {
      value: ""
    }],
    website: {
      name: "",
      url: ""
    },
    load: function(id) {

    },
    helper1: function() {
      // implementation
    },
    helper2: function() {
      // implementation
    }
    // many other helpers...
  }
  return Blog;
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Blog) {
  $scope.model = new Blog(12);
});
```

And finally my view

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.22"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Name <input ng-model="model.name"></p>
    <div ng-repeat="line in model.description">
      Description line {{$index}} <input ng-model="line.value">
    </div>
    <p>Website name <input ng-model="model.website.name"></p>
    <p>Website url <input ng-model="model.website.url"></p>
    <p>Result : {{ model | json  }}</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

To illustrate the problem, i have created a [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/TMgC4Gw4QHgGhctVPvX7?p=preview)
When entering the values in the input fields, the `Model` is not updated with the changes.  Only the field `name` is updated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services are instanced by Angular and then a reference of them is injected where ever it is asked for. 
Just change the code as following

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('Blog', function() {

  return {
    name: "",
    description: [
            {value: ""},
            {value: ""},
            {value: ""}
        ],
    website: {
      name: "",
      url: ""
    },
    helper1: function() {
      // implementation
    },
    helper2: function() {
      // implementation
    }
    // many other helpers...
  }
  //return new Blog(); 
});  

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Blog) { 
  $scope.model = Blog;
});
```

There is a slight difference in way in which services, factories and provider works. I hope you are clear on that other wise read this excellent article

http://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider/

NEW plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/FGOcPWVMeFDSyVtmv8Xd?p=preview

The factory exposes a new method using which you can create new instances of Blog.

I think its also because JSON filter is implemented you are not able to see all the values.
Because decription and website and url are in proto of the object, it's not displaying it.

I added a button for logging the model, you can see in the console that the value is changed

**Edit 2**

*Q: I don't understand why the JSON filter is not displaying the values ?*

A: I think it could be how its implemented, may be to make it light weight. Otherwise it has to walk through it's entire prototype chain

*Q: Why the values are placed into the **proto** because of the nature of Blog ?*

A: its because you add the values in the Blog's prototype and not inside Blog itself. It's how prototypical inheritence works in javascript. The advantage is think when you have to create 1000s of blog's instances. Now each instance can have the same methods and properties or to make it light weight, each instance can share the same object which is in its proto.(think of base class in OO language)
Read this for more clarity

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: Thanks @anand, this is working, what about the constructor?  `function Blog() {}` I forgot to mention that i my app i'm passing some parameters when I do the `new`

Comment: Thanks again @anand, this answer is the best.  Last comment, I don't understand why the JSON filter is not displaying the values? Why the values are placed into the `__proto__` because of the nature of `Blog` ? again Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Blog here is a service that should be created by a factory. Your factory should return the new instance / a value / or a function.

You don't create an instance of the Blog that was injected to your controller, what is injected should already be the only instance available to everything that will be injected to others.

Hence, services are singleton (created by the factory).

Comment: Just what I was going to say :)